# Relaunch android app in Unity (No working anymore in Android 10)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I used to be able to restart my Unity application on Android through:

```
using (AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        {
            AndroidJavaObject pm = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
            AndroidJavaObject intent = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", Application.identifier);
            intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setFlags", 0x20000000);//Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

            AndroidJavaClass pendingIntent = new AndroidJavaClass("android.app.PendingIntent");
            AndroidJavaObject contentIntent = pendingIntent.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getActivity", currentActivity, 0, intent, 0x8000000); //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT = 134217728 [0x8000000]
            AndroidJavaObject alarmManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "alarm");
            AndroidJavaClass system = new AndroidJavaClass("java.lang.System");
            long currentTime = system.CallStatic<long>("currentTimeMillis");
            alarmManager.Call("set", 1, currentTime + 1000, contentIntent); // android.app.AlarmManager.RTC = 1 [0x1]

            Debug.LogError("alarm_manager set time " + currentTime + 1000);
            currentActivity.Call("finish");

            AndroidJavaClass process = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Process");
            int pid = process.CallStatic<int>("myPid");
            process.CallStatic("killProcess", pid);
        }
```

I read that Android 10 changed the way activities may be started:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

But I'm not sure why this isn't working anymore. Does anyone know how I can restart a Unity app on Android 10?